# Continuously save data in label to column in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

I'm having trouble in saving my data in labels. It always overwrites when I save it. Saving data to column B is okay, but when it turns to column C, it overwrites it. Data in Column B will be erased. Only column C is saved.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application OfficeExcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook OfficeWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet OfficeSheet;

        try
        {
            //Start Excel and get Application object.
            OfficeExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            OfficeExcel.Visible = true;

            //Get a new workbook.
            OfficeWorkBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(OfficeExcel.Workbooks.Add(""));
            OfficeSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)OfficeWorkBook.ActiveSheet;


            int apple = 10, banana = 11, grapes = 12, orange = 5;
            int apple2 = 20, banana2 = 21, grapes2 = 22, orange2 = 15;


            switch (cmbDays.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    lbltotalapple.Text = apple.ToString();
                    lbltotalbanana.Text = banana.ToString();
                    lbltotalgrapes.Text = grapes.ToString();
                    lbltotalorange.Text = orange.ToString();
                    //Add table headers going cell by cell.

                    OfficeSheet.Cells[3, 2] = lbltotalapple.Text;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[4, 2] = lbltotalbanana.Text;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[5, 2] = lbltotalgrapes.Text;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[6, 2] = lbltotalorange.Text;

                    OfficeExcel.Visible = false;
                    OfficeExcel.UserControl = false;

                    // I think is the problem. How do I make it continously save. Not overwriting it.
                    OfficeWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\test\\test1.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel7, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    OfficeWorkBook.Close();

                    break;

                case "2":
                    lbltotalapple.Text = apple2.ToString();
                    lbltotalbanana.Text = banana2.ToString();
                    lbltotalgrapes.Text = grapes2.ToString();
                    lbltotalorange.Text = orange2.ToString();

                    OfficeSheet.Cells[3, 3] = lbltotalapple.Text;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[4, 3] = lbltotalbanana.Text;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[5, 3] = lbltotalgrapes.Text;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[6, 3] = lbltotalorange.Text;

                    OfficeExcel.Visible = false;
                    OfficeExcel.UserControl = false;

                    // I think is the problem. How do I make it continously save. Not overwriting it.
                    OfficeWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\test\\test1.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel7, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    OfficeWorkBook.Close();

                    break;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                   // do something
        }


    }
```

How do I get it continuously to save from column B to C and so on?

Comment: You are saving the file as new test1.xls in both cases, which is why it is over-writing the existing file. Check if there is already test1.xls file and open it, that way it adds the column c data.

Comment: @SteveEd I try to open it but everytime i open it create a new instance not the old one. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @SteveEd. Thank you for helping. I finally solve it.